# how do i install beautifulsoup to python 2.7 in ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, python, python-2.7

I think I'm missing a dependency for a chat bot I'm writing. I'm trying to install beautifulsoup4 for python 2.7.

The program is returning this error when I try to use the function in question

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:794:
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. 
Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See:
https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html InsecureRequestWarning)
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function run at 0x7f24085aaaa0>

Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "core/main.py", line 77, in run    
    out = func(input.inp, **kw)    
  File "plugins/comic.py", line 88, in comic    
    return val['data']['link']    
KeyError: 'link'
```

After some searching it seems like it might be related to a missing dependency (beautifulsoup, in this case)

Comment: How did you know you need to install Beautiful Soup?

Comment: i googled some of the error code that seemed relevant. i also googled to try and find the answer i asked here but didnt seem to write the question properly to get an answer i understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-bs4
```

Beautiful Soup (python-bs4) is an error-tolerant HTML parser for Python 2.x. There are two different packages: python-bs4 (for Python 2.x) and python3-bs4 (for Python 3.x), and to prevent you from getting confused there are also two different Integrated Development Environments for Python: IDLE and IDLE 3 to run them in.

Comment: Thank you that did install the package. Seems like that fixed the issue, which of course only opened up more issues. 

Brand new to linux and this is my first time ever doing anything with python or anything like this ever. Learning a lot and having fun. Thanks again